# Why recording audio gives error "buffer full" after 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, naudio

Following code gives me the error 'Buffer full' and I have no idea why. My code was supposed to give me wave chart while it's recording the audio. However, wave chart is working and the after 5 seconds above error is brought to the screen my the program

I'm new to this.

```
private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnRecord.Text == "Record")
            {
                sources = new List<NAudio.Wave.WaveInCapabilities>();

                for (int i = 0; i < NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
                {
                    sources.Add(NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i));
                }

                input = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
                input.DeviceNumber = 0;
                input.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0).Channels);

                NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(input);

                waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
                waveOut.Init(waveIn);

                input.StartRecording();

                //waveOut.Play();
                input.DataAvailable += input_DataAvailable;
                btnRecord.Text = "Stop Record";
            }
            else if (btnRecord.Text == "Stop Record")
            {
                waveOut.Stop();
                input.StopRecording();
                btnRecord.Text = "Record";
                input.Dispose();

            }
        }

private void input_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            memStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);            


            RawSourceWaveStream rawSource = new RawSourceWaveStream(memStream, input.WaveFormat);
            customWaveViewer2.WaveStream = rawSource;
            rawSource.Flush();
            memStream.Flush();
        }
```

The following would be stacktrace

```
at NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider.waveIn_DataAvailable(Object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.RaiseDataAvailable(WaveInBuffer buffer)
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.Callback(IntPtr waveInHandle, WaveMessage message, IntPtr userData, WaveHeader waveHeader, IntPtr reserved)
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Pitch_Comparer.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Nadeesha\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Pitch_Comparer\Pitch_Comparer\Program.cs:line 19
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Is this your complete code? I'd suspect you do some processing with the incoming samples.

Comment: Like what?Could you elaborate more?

Comment: I guess you use up too much CPU during recording, thast's why some buffers show overflows

Comment: I just restarted the windows. It's still the same...!

Comment: I meant: in **your code** you use up too much cpu. What are you doing with these incoming samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WaveInProvider` is recording audio and putting it into a `BufferedWaveProvider`. So your `WaveOut` needs to be playing or the buffer will fill up. (so uncomment waveOut.Play in order to fix the issue).

If you don't actually want to play the audio you're recording, then just use a regular `WaveIn`, not `WaveInProvider`.